# SwiftUI View memory lifecycle

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui, combine

I have main View which has ViewModel and it's declared like this

`@ObservedObject var viewModel = ViewModel()`

Everything works perfectly but when I move the app to background and then to foreground the View recreates itself as well as my viewModel and everything stored in viewModel disappears.

In this case making ViewModel a singleton class will solve the problem but making all ViewModels singleton classes is not a good idea.

Is there a workaround for this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you’re building for iOS 14, have a look at @StateObject. SwiftUI creates @StateObject only once for every container that declares it and keeps it outside of view lifecycle. It means that the view owns the value and the value's lifecycle is tied to the view's lifecycle, not the struct.

More information here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/stateobject

Answer (score 2):

Making an `ObservedObject` singleton is not a good idea for other reasons. Since you want to preview your views, you have to inject somehow your viewmodel to make it easier on more complex cases.

Whenever I would need a singleton in `SwiftUI` I consider using an `EnvironmentObject` added from the `SceneDelegate` (in the real application) or from the `PreviewProvider` in case of a preview. If you store the reference in your `SceneDelegate` it will not recreate.

On the memory leak concern, the viewmodel should not leak, if it has no retain cycles in it. It would get cleaned up by ARC.

Answer (score 0):

For data that should be shared SwiftUI gives us `@EnvironmentObject`